# How to capture image in ARKit with 3D model

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am adding few 3D models in my current ARSession. I want to get current camera viewing image with 3D object. Using ARFrame I am only getting raw pixebuffer. Is there any way to get pixel buffer with 3D object?

Comment: Do you need to get it every frame or "once in a while"?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SceneKit to render AR objects (that is, your view is an `ARSCNView`), use the [`snapshot()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1524031-snapshot) method (defined by the superclass, `SCNView`) to get an image of the view's entire contents (including both the camera image and any virtual objects).